# Is there a way to make a list box show that there are multiples of one item without having two rows with the same item if an add button is clicked?

Tags: c#, button, listbox, items

An example to clarify:
I have three items, each of which has an add button to show the name of the item in a list box. If I click add it will show the item once, if I click add again it will show the item twice in the list box. That is with this simple code under the click event handler-

```
ListBox.Items.Add("ItemName");
```

Is there a way I can code the button or list box to instead of showing repetitive lines, to show a "x2" or something similar when an item is added twice or more?

I'm using C# and windows form app.

Comment: if you already have a 'x 2', what if you add a new item named 'x 2'? i prefer ListView for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the way I would come at that:

```
    private readonly Dictionary<string, int> _dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    private void AddNewItem(string item)
    {
        if (_dict.ContainsKey(item)) _dict[item]++;
        else _dict.Add(item,1);
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in _dict)
        {
            if (kvp.Value > 1) listBox1.Items.Add(kvp.Key + " X" + kvp.Value);
            else listBox1.Items.Add(kvp.Key);
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewItem("ItemName");
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I would create a custom class (say, `CountableItem`) and give it quantity and name fields.  We can then override the `ToString()` method to determine what will be displayed in the ListBox.

Something like this:

```
internal class CountableItem
{
    private string _itemName;
    private int _count;

    public CountableItem(string itemName)
    {
        _itemName = itemName;
        _count = 1;
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
        _count++;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} x {1}", _itemName, _count);
    }
}
```

You can add instances of `CountableItem` to the listbox and then use the `Increment()` method to increase the quantity.

You will of course need logic to determine whether or not a given `CountableItem` is already in the ListBox.